# Android - Is there a layout with normalized coordinates

Tags: android, android-layout, eclipse-adt

Is there a layout in Android that can do layout using a normalized coordinate system?
I don't think any of the available ones does that.

Do I have to create custom layout?
If so, can I use Android Eclipse ADT graphics layout editor to create my layout xml that uses my custom layout?

Comment: what do you mean by normalized coordinate system?

Comment: A layout where child views are bound in a [0 to 1] space vertically and horizontally.

Comment: there is no such layout, you need a simple custom ViewGroup

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you. Please add this in answers. I will accept.

Answer (score 1):

LinearLayout has a layoutWeight attribute that might help

Comment: I am aware of LinearLayout.. But it can arrange either vertically/horizontally only. What I need is a 2D-normalized coordinate system within this layout

Comment: gridLayout or tableLayout ?

Comment: You can use horizontally-orientated LinearLayouts inside vertically-orientated ones and vice versa. To me it seems to be the easiest way to implement such an interface.

Comment: I think that makes the layout too much complex. I feel I can probably choose the solution suggested by @pskink